# Mysql two tables, select all values from one table, compare if exists and then return One random value

Tags: php, mysql, random

I'm new here as for posting questions, but I've been looking for answers since long time ago.
Still what I'm trying to do now I didn't found for the right solution or I just didn't know how to use it if I did found it.

Here's my SQL query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_links AS link_id WHERE link_points > '1' 
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table_surf AS slink_id WHERE user_id = '$user'
AND surf_time = '$time') ORDER by RAND() LIMIT 1";
```

I'm trying to select a random LINK id (wich has points) and check if that link was allready shown to a user today by looking into the 2nd table where all LINK ID's are saved as SLINK ID's with user ID's and time of the last visits.

If last visit was today (`$time`) then it should not return anything.

I'm  new to PHP/mysql but I'm trying to learn, still this is a situation where I'm not sure if it is even possible to realise a complex query like this one.

UPDATE: Based on Akhil post this is what seems to work for me -

> $sql = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT RAND() temp, link_id FROM table_links WHERE link_points > '1' AND link_status NOT IN ('spam') AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT slink_id FROM table_surf AS links WHERE user_id = '$user' AND surf_time = '$time' AND slink_id = '$surflink')) a ORDER by temp LIMIT 1";

Comment: Avoid using select * from as much as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a sub query

```
$sql = "select * from (SELECT RAND() temp, table_links.* FROM table_links AS link_id WHERE link_points > '1' 
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table_surf AS slink_id WHERE user_id = '$user'
AND surf_time = '$time')) a  ORDER by temp LIMIT 1";
```

See if it solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

If your link id column is called my_link_id in table `table_links` then use the `NOT IN` like this

`$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_links AS link_id WHERE link_points > '1' 
AND link_id.my_link_id NOT IN (SELECT * FROM table_surf AS slink_id WHERE user_id = '$user'
AND surf_time = '$time') ORDER by RAND() LIMIT 1";`

Comment: NOT IN needs a field to verify against

Comment: oh yes so dumb of me lol .. was in a hurry .. does it look right now @skv ?

Comment: are we assuming that the link_id is the only field in table_surf table? if so please make it explicit

Comment: No, link_id is not the only field, it has thousands of links from few hundred users and they are indexed.

Comment: That was earlier .. now the query is selecting the link properly from `link_id.my_link_id` this will have many links .. then we check whether any of those links have been already visited in the subquery. If they are NOT IN them then we order them randomly and select only 1. Does that help @user2669973 ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_link1 
        WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM table_link2) ORDER BY RAND()" LIMIT 1;
```